# jQuery and webkit, how to get css({top:, left:}) to work?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, safari, webkit

I was trying to do something nice to display an error message, and everything was fine until I decided to try with chrome/safari, this is the code:

Here: http://pastebin.com/VymWLNTT

Or here: http://jsfiddle.net/YfrVJ/

Does anyone know a workaround or another similar way to display error messages?, thanks.

Comment: i've updated your jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YfrVJ/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without further inspection: +=50% fails. Change it to an absolute pixel value and it will work.

Edit: Alternatively remove "+=".

http://jsfiddle.net/LTgUY/1/

Comment: Same conclusion I was able to come to. The 50% fails. I was able to switch to `$(window).height()/2` and get it to work on all tests.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the percentage value used with `.animate` with an absolute value. You can calculate it in a similar manner as you do with the `vleft` value, e.g.:

```
var topDelta = ($(window).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2;
```

Then use it instead of the `50%`:

```
this.animate({ opacity:0.8, top: '+=' + topDelta }, ...
```

Comment: thanks, I had forgotten that 50% (or $(window).height()/2) alone wouldn't put the thing in the middle